# How to calculate a confidence interval for $p$, the parameter of the binomial distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose I have a random variable X that is known to follow the binomial distribution B, but whose parameter $p$ is unknown.

I have observed 100 samples of X, and they all came out true.

How can I calculate a 95% confidence interval for the value of $p$ (which stands for P(true)) of the underlying distribution B?

Comment: When all the observations are the same, there is the [rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(statistics)) which in this case would suggest a confidence interval of $\left[\frac{100-3}{100},\frac{100}{100}\right]=[0.97,1]$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, the usual use of the notation $\hat{p}$ refers to the (point) *estimate* and **not** the true underlying value of the parameter. Many answers to your question are available in standard texts.

The [Clopper–Pearson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Clopper-Pearson_interval) interval is the most popular. It is *guaranteed* to give at least 95% coverage for *all* values of the underlying parameter. It is actually more stringent, in that it ensures that there is no more than 2.5% non-coverage in each tail (i.e. it is a "central" interval). As a consequence it tends to be quite conservative. That said, the typical "approximate intervals" (e.g., Wald and score) both fail miserably if the true proportion is close to 0 or 1.

Another exact method which is nested within (and usually narrower than) the Clopper–Pearson interval can be found in

> H. Blaker, [Confidence curves and improved exact confidence intervals for discrete distributions](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.34.9682&rep=rep1&type=pdf), *Canadian J. Stat.*, vol 28, 2000, 783–798.

Unlike the Copper–Pearson interval, there is no closed form for the Blaker interval, but [software](http://CRAN.R-project.org/package=BlakerCI) is available.

Agresti also covers this in Section 1.4.4 (pp. 18–21) of *Categorical Data Analysis*, 2nd. edition. (This is the larger green book, not the smaller one of almost the same name.)

For 100 successes in 100 trials, the Clopper–Pearson confidence interval is $(0.9638, 1.0)$ and the Blaker confidence interval is $(0.9644, 1.0)$.

Comment: Fixed the hat. Thanks!

Comment: Very useful answer. Using my original numbers and [this calculator](http://statpages.org/confint.html), we can be 95% confident that $p$ lies between 0.9638 and 1.0.